# How do you enable clicking on individual items in an array and display each item in a different part of the screen in Phaser 3?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm working on a word scramble game using Phaser 3 and javascript. So far I've been able to display a scrambled word on the screen with a click of a button. Now I need the user to be able to click on what they think is the first letter of the word that's scrambled. If they are right, the letter gets placed above the scrambled word somewhere, and they continue that until the word is correctly spelled out. If they click on the wrong letter, it doesn't get placed above, so they try again. I don't know what to do next. Here's what I have so far:

```
public onSceneCreated() {
     // Fit world to screen
        this.scene.game.scale.scaleMode = Phaser.Scale.FIT;
        this.scene.game.scale.refresh(PhaserHelper.worldSize.width, PhaserHelper.worldSize.height);

    // See the world size, eventually remove
       this.scene.cameras.main.setBackgroundColor("rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)");

    let centerX = PhaserHelper.worldSize.width / 2;
    let centerY = PhaserHelper.worldSize.height / 2;   
    
    // Random word picked from array
    let word = this.activityItems[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.activityItems.length)];
    
    // Function that scrambles a word
    let scramble = (a) => {
        a = a.split("");
        for(let b = a.length - 1; 0 < b; b--) {
            let c = Math.floor(Math.random()*(b + 1));
            let d = a[b];
                a[b] = a[c];
                a[c] = d;
        }
         return a.join("");
    }        

    // Adds button (clickable text)
    let clickButton = this.scene.add.text(1000, 800, 'Button', { 
        fontFamily: Fonts.BalsamiqSans,
        fontSize: 50,
        color: Colors.black,
         });    
        clickButton.setInteractive();
    // Display scrambled word by clicking button
        clickButton.on('pointerdown', () => {
    this.scene.add.text(centerX, centerY, scramble(`${word.answer.text}`), {
        fontFamily: Fonts.BalsamiqSans,
        fontSize: 100,
        color: Colors.black,
        });
     });
    console.log(`${word.answer.text}`);
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know phaser but this might help you with the idea in javascript

```js
var cnt =  0 

var spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
for(i=0;i<spans.length;i++)
    spans[i].onclick=getLetter;

function getLetter(){

var correct = document.getElementById('correct')

    var letter =this.innerHTML
    
    
    if (cnt == 0 && letter == 'v'){
       correct.innerHTML = 'v'
       cnt++
    }
    else if( cnt == 1 && letter == 'o')
    {
       correct.innerHTML = 'vo'
       cnt++
    }
    else if( cnt == 2 && letter == 't')
    {
       correct.innerHTML = 'vot'
       cnt++  
    }
    else if( cnt == 3 && letter == 'e')
    {
       correct.innerHTML = 'vote'
       cnt++
    }
    else if( cnt == 4 && letter == 's')
    {
       correct.innerHTML = 'votes'
       cnt++      
    }
}
```

```css
span{
display:inline-block;
border:solid 1px black;
width:20px;

margin:5px;
padding:5px;
text-align:center;
}

#correct{
margin:50px;
}

#scrambled{
border:solid black 1px;
width:210px;}
```

```html
<div id="correct"></div>
<div id='scrambled'><span>e</span><span>o</span><span>v</span><span>s</span><span>t</span></div>
```